# How to avoid duplicate outputs in java text files?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem guys.

I have created a simple system for login using text file in java.

My text file has records like this:

```
Hamada 114455
Ahmed  236974145
Johny  4123745
```

the programming format for these records are like this:

```
String username, int password
```

The problem is at login operation, the system should work like this:

```
username: Ahmed
password: 114455
```

the system should search for username and password in the text file, if they exist then it says "Welcome :)".

if not it says "Wrong username or pasword"

the problem: if i enter wrong username or password then it writes wrong username or password for each line that not found the username and password in.

here is my code:

```
                System.out.println("Login Page");
                System.out.printf("Username: ");
                String user2 = input.next();
                System.out.printf("Password: ");
                int pass2 = input.nextInt();
                Scanner y = null;
                try{
                y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt"));
                while(y.hasNext())
                {
                String a = y.next();
                int b = y.nextInt();
                if((a == null ? user2 == null : a.equals(user2)) && b == pass2)
                    System.out.println("Welcome :)");
                else
                    System.out.println("Wrong username or password .. try again !!");
                }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, use a `boolean` variable (initialised to `false`). 
If an entry with the same data is found, set it to `true`.

then print the results, outside of the while loop.

```
boolean userExists = false;
while (y.hasNext()) {
  // .....
  if((a == null ? user2 == null : a.equals(user2)) && b == pass2)
    userExists = true;

  // ...
}

if (userExists)
  System.out.println("Welcome");
else
  System.out.println("Wrong username or password .. try again !!");
```

Comment: For better efficiency you can also `break` the while-loop when an entry is matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
 boolean bool = false;
Scanner y = null;
try{
y = new Scanner(new File("Path"));
while(y.hasNext())
{
String a = y.next();
int b = y.nextInt();
if((a == null ? user2 == null : a.equals(user2)) && b == pass2)
    bool = true;
}
if(bool) 
    System.out.println("Welcome :)");
else 
    System.out.println("Wrong username or password .. try again !!");
}
```

Well in your case you are checking the if else condition for each entry in the text file. Also you the showing the message on console for each entry. I have modified the program and writing to console after exiting the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code in this way:

```
boolean isWrong = true ;
while(y.hasNext())
{
    String a = y.next();
    int b = y.nextInt();
    if((a == null ? user2 == null : a.equals(user2)) && b == pass2)
        isWrong = false ;
}
if(isWrong) 
    System.out.println("Wrong username or password .. try again !!");
else
    System.out.println("Welcome :)");
```